# CQL3 IN clause on tuples - Bad Request reported by cqlsh

Tags: select, cql3, cassandra-2.0

I tried to run the select ... where ... in ... example from cassandra docs here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    userid text,
    blog_title text,
    posted_at timestamp,
    entry_title text,
    content text,
    category int,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, blog_title, posted_at)
);

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid='john doe' 
  AND (blog_title, posted_at) IN (('John''s Blog', '2012-01-01'), ('Extreme Chess', '2014-06-01'))
```

Except I added ' after first timestamp literal missing in the example. I get:

```
Bad Request: line 1:106 missing EOF at ','
```

Running cassandra 2.0.8, cqlsh 4.1.1, tried both cql default 3.1.0 and 3.0.0.
Do I have to do something more, or was support for this feature removed?

Comment: Seems like it might be a deficiency in this version of Cassandra/cqlsh. FWIW, those exact statements work without error in 2.1. I haven't found a bug describing this error, or when it was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra 2.1 was announced today; from the release announcement:

> "For us developers, the biggest game changer in 2.1 is the introduction of CQL3 tuple..."

This may be what you're looking for.